# Clarification on "Tawaffa"

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, death, prophet-isa

To the best of my knowledge, whenever Allah or His angels perform tawaffa on someone it only means sleep or death.

25+ times only death:

وتوفنا مع الأبرار 3:193

الذين يتوفون منكم 2:234 & 2:240

توفني مسلما وألحقني بالصالحين 12:101

و لكن أعبد الله الذي يتوفاكم 10:104

و منكم من يتوفى 22:5

توفته رسلنا و هم لا يفرطون 6:61

And regarding the Holy Prophet (sa) 10:46 & 13:40 & 40:77 فإما نرينك بعض الذي نعدهم أو نتوفينك

etc.

2 times it can also mean sleep, but in both cases there is a clear indicator present:

39:42 - في منامها in their sleep

6:60 - بالليل in the night

So to the best of my knowledge whenever Allah does tawaffa on someone it means taking their soul. In the case of death he keeps the soul. In the case of sleep he sends it back to the body.

So how does tawaffa mean "take [the physical body, implied by most Muslims]" in the context of Jesus (as)?

Where else in the Quran is tawaffa used like this? (When Allah is the فاعل and a souled being is the مفعول)

Jazakallah

Comment: Basically only the passive from of توفى (تُوُفِّيَ) means he died this is clearaly the case for 22:5. The active form must be interpreted in the context as it is an expression about a duration or to be taken in context of an aftermath it mostly is related with the verbs "to take", "to let/keep". So your first verse 3:193 means let us be resurrected with the good people and so is the case for 12:101 among the examples out of your list.

Comment: I suppose you mean verse [39:42](https://legacy.quran.com/39/42) not [39:40](https://legacy.quran.com/39/40)! Please cross check your list and add links to the correct verses.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes you are correct jazakallah for catching this

Comment: @Medi1Saif I've never seen "tawaffa" translated as "let us be resurrected" as you have for 3:193. Any reference for this?

Comment: As stated it is the context that supports only this meaning because it is certainly not die with good people than be resurrected in the hereafter with good people. Further the Qur'an was revealed in Arabic translations can't be regarded as equal nor even close to the real meaning. And this is agreed upon among scholars of tafsir since the early days of Islam

Comment: @Medi1Saif That context should be based on the Quran. Not Ahadith. And you didn't answer my question about 3:193 tawaffa meaning "let us be resurrected". I asked for a reference? Because I've always found it to mean "let us die among the righteous" and see no context that would require a different translation that negates death.

Comment: The context is the verse itself if you don't understand it because you follow a misleading translation I can't help you more than I've done by explaining the incompatibility of your interpretation in my explanation above. I have nowhere claimed it to be based on Hadith that's simply your wrong interpretation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So 3:193 tawaffa meaning "let us die" is wrong? That's what I'm asking lol

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean sleep in 39:40. It means take. The مفعول به are the souls, not the person. Allah says He takes the souls in their sleep. This meaning is essentially what is being claimed for Isa AS (being taken).

As for the rest of the verses, it is simply an idiom in Arabic to say "taken" to mean death because the dead person's soul was taken. But, the existence of this idiom doesn't make the literal meaning impossible.

No different to how we say "he passed" in English. It doesn't indicate to pass literally means to die, and it doesn't mean we can never use the word pass literally for a person.

Comment: Are there any cases where it means to take the body too? Other than with Jesus (as) ofc. Because elsewhere it just means death in my study.

Comment: @NoWorries The concept of people being "taken" with their bodies is unsurprisingly rare. We only know of one incident of that happening. So, I'm not sure what other case you expect to find.

Comment: And as for what I've seen nafs doesn't refer just to the soul. That would be Ruh. Nafs is more for being, individual, person. Body and the soul. Or is nafs and ruh the exact same?

Comment: So tawaffa means "take physical body" only for Jesus (as)?

Comment: @NoWorries Nafs can mean person or soul. In this verse, it means soul and doesn't include the body since Allah says he keeps some of the nafs and lets some go. That's all referring to the soul.

Comment: @NoWorries By necessity, Isa AS can be the only example of someone being taken with his body. So, yes, he is the only example but that is entirely expected. It doesn't mean take physical body. It just means take him and it includes all of him.

Comment: Jazakallah for your clarification. As for myself I will not make a unique meaning of tawaffa for Jesus (as) and will take it to mean death as is prevalent in the Quran. But to each their own I guess.

Comment: @NoWorries You may do as you wish. But, keep in mind that the fact Jesus (AS) will return near the end of times is mass-transmitted (mutawatir) from the Prophet SAW. Anyone who denies that would be considered a non-Muslim for denying the clear words of the Prophet. So, whether or not you take this interpretation, you have to believe he will return, however you interpret that to happen (perhaps he will be resurrected and sent back or something).

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2476

Comment: @NoWorries Also, don't misunderstand what tawaffa means. Tawaffa doesn't itself mean death. It means to take. It is an idiom to refer to death commonly like "to pass" is an idiom to refer to death.

Comment: Im sorry brother but I do not feel comfortable changing the meanings of the Quran to suit the Ahadith. If there is no instance in the Quran that tawaffa means taking of the body then I cannot apply that meaning to Jesus (as), no matter what any hadith says. " فَبِاَیِّ حَدِیۡثٍۭ بَعۡدَ اللّٰہِ وَاٰیٰتِہٖ یُؤۡمِنُوۡنَ"  45:6.  Likewise as you say tawaffa is an idiom to refer to death like "pass". So Jesus (as) passed away. No other meaning should be made for Jesus (as) when the verses of the Quran do not say otherwise.

Comment: The ahadith dont talk about a "return" or a "second coming" to the best of my knowledge. The word used is ينزل "descend" not يرجع "return." Are there any ahadith that specifically say that the same Jesus (as) who was رسول الى بني اسرائيل will "return"?

Comment: The Quran using the same word to mean different things in different places isn't uncommon such that you can pretend it would be changing the Quran to understand it that way. The Prophet literally says "the son of Maryam" and it is clear whom that refers to. There is no other Isa ibn Maryam that we know of.

Comment: Additionally, as I said, if you don't feel comfortable with tawaffa meaning that, that is fine. You can interpret this verse as meaning sleep or death, while still accepting that Isa ibn Maryam will return. And the idea that there is someone else who is Isa is idiotic and I have only seen disbelievers like Qadiyanis believe it, trying to twist the clear narrations.

Comment: To each their own I guess. This isn't a platform for prolonged discussion otherwise I'd discuss this topic with you further. If you want a further discussion with me I'm down for that. We can get further in contact via reddit Emotional_Ebb_1292 (facebook or twitter is fine too but I don't feel comfortable sharing it here)